# How to add WiFi password and static IP to OSMC, before saving the image?

Tags: wireless, disk-image

I would like (using Ubuntu 18.04) to save my Wifi password and a static IP on an [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/) disc image before "burning" this image to an SD card to be used in my raspberry pi 3.

The reason is that I have a fairly long and not particularly human legible Wifi password and a rather terrible keyboard on the pi.

I have done this before on a raspberry 2 and XBMC, but I do not remember how...

Answer (score -1):

Network passwords are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and you can create a static IP for your device by changing your `/etc/network/interfaces` file to something like below:

```
# The wifi network interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.87
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8
    wpa-ssid <Your wifi network SSID>
    wpa-psk <Your hex encoded wifi WPA password>
```

Then you can create your image of the system.

Comment: That's not correct for wifi. You haven't specified the SSID and, if needed, WPA2 password. It is unlikely that the wifi interface is eth0.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I misread that. I updated it to show what a wifi interface might look like.

Comment: The interfaces file expects to see the WPA2 password in clear text, not hex encoded. Also, network and broadcast are not needed.

Comment: I need to do this on the image before burning it to the sd card. So how do I modify the image?